# 2008 SSRS report in VS 2010 solution

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2008 SSRS report and I'm trying to call in it in VS 2010 solution. But it giving me login errors. Can anyone give me the best solution for it...

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

2008 reports are compatible in 2010.  If the 2010 VS is not on the same server as the 2008, this may be causing your issue as the connection to the Datasets are not working.  Does depend on where you are getting the login errors.